# не получается вывести len из БД

Tags: php

```
<?php
session_start();
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "regauth") or die("Error!!!");

if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
    header("location: ../../");

if($_GET['link'] === 'logout'){
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    session_destroy();
    header("location: ../../");
}
// $formdata = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
  $len=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['nameselect']));
// $names = $formdata['nameselect'];
// $names_str = implode(', ', $names);

    if(isset($_POST['do-len'])){
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO users (login,password,name,email,img,len) VALUES ('$login', '$password','$name','$email','$img','$len') ");  
 }

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Личный кабинет</title>
</head>

<body>
<div><?php echo "Привет, ".$_SESSION['user'][1]; ?> | <a href="index.php?link=logout">Выйти</a>
</div>
<h3>Создание заявки</h3>
<form  method="post">
<p><select size="3" name="nameselect" multiple>
    <option value="Тест1">Тест1</option>
    <option value="Тест2">Тест2</option>
    <option value="Тест3">Тест3</option>
   </select></p>
   <p><input type="submit" name="do-len"value="Отправить"></p>
   </form>
   <h3>Просмотр своих записей на курсы</h3>
  <?php
  // $sql=mysql_query("select * from `users` where 'len' ");если не получится 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE len IN ('".implode(",",$len)."') ";
/*
символ '*' указывает, что нужно выбрать все столбцы
если Вам нужен один или несколько столбцов, укажите какие
это сократит нагрузку на MySQL и время вывода информации
например, нам нужны только заголовок и текст
*/

$result=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

# выводим результат
print "$result[len]";

   ?>

   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Начните с нормального. Уберите `implode` в отдельную переменную, а не то, как сейчас у Вас. Затем почитайте про LENGTH. Если хотите использовать len - почитайте, как правильно его использовать.

Comment: `mysql_`, `mysqli_`, не мешало бы разобраться чем они отличаются.

Comment: я знаю чем они отличаются вопрос был в другом